# Получить высоту контента из WebView

Tags: android, webview

Есть WebView в который помещаю html код и нужно измерить высоту контента и установить layout_height у WebView.

```
<WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#fdfdfd"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false" />

WebView web= (WebView) rootView[position]
                        .findViewById(R.id.web);
web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(
                        LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                    "<style>*{font-size:13px!important;font-family:arial!important;line-height:19px!important;} "
                            + "img{vertical-align:middle;}</style>"
                            + "<div id='cont_quest' >"
                            + text
                            + "</div>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Использую javascript

```
document.getElementById('cont_quest').clientHeight
```

Далее конвертирую из px в dp (возможно тут я не прав) и к этому значению ещё прибавляю 40.

```
(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, Value, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

На телефоне в 95% случаев правильно указывает LayoutParams, а вот на планшете слишком большая высота получается. Пробовал и offsetHeight и scrollHeight, дело не в javascript. Как правильно получить высоту контента?

Comment: Глупая идея. Высота WebView должна занимать ВСЕ пространство активности. Уже внутри самого компонента масштабируйте контент с помощью JavaScript.

Comment: Помимо WebView есть ещё другие элементы без которых, нет смысла в приложении. Компонент заполняется не только текстом, но и изображениями, поэтому не получится сделать статическую высоту у WebView и подгонять через JavaScript. Поэтому ваша отрицательная оценка не обоснованна. WebView находится с другими элементами в ScrollView, и нужно избежать скроллинга в WebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему помещением фрагмента состоящего из *WebView* во *FrameLayout* с высотой *wrap_content*